# Intermittent loss of DNS server

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, dns, proxy

Lately I have been having this issue which is often preceded by using the remote shutdown tool of teamviewer.

After the computer (Windows 7) is rebooted it initially connects to the network and from then on has this issue.

For the first few minutes of being on everything, meaning all network related programs like Chrome and other browsers, works fine. Then all browsers stop working. As in, if they are already running they crash and if they are opened afterwards they display 'resolving host'  forever.

The reason I think its a DNS problem with my computer specifically is because I can still ping any IP address, both inside and outside my network.

Also no other devices in my network are having any issues.

I have tried:

- clearing the DNS cache
- restarting the NIC
- rebooting/restarting.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The last time I encountered a similar problem, the procedure below was able to resolve the issue.

Try resetting the TCP/IP stack in Windows to see if that resolves your issue.

Open an elevated command prompt:

- Press start button, type in `cmd`, right click and select "Run as administrator".

then type in the command:

`netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt`

[Additional info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357/en) from Microsoft.

Comment: No luck, tried it and restarted and after restart got the same thing.  Thanks though!

Comment: Try probing DNS with [NSlookup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) in the command line. If it doesn't work try and see if you can get lookups with google DNS  ( IP: 8.8.8.8 ) to confirm whether or not it's actually a DNS issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to use this tool also I found the error I'm getting, its dns_probe_finished_no_internet